# How can I create a link that adds my event to others' calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, web, calendar, google-calendar, calendar.app

I want to make it easy for people who sign up for one of my events to add the event's data to their calendars.

I'd like to make it so easy that they just click a link on my site and their calendars take it from there.

The 3 calendars my people are likely to use: Google Calendar, Outlook, ical

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about putting a link to a calendar on a website? How automated do you want this process to be? Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve here, this may be a more appropriate question for Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure.

Google Calendar, Outlook and iCal can all import the [ical format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) (`.ics). Outlook and Google Calendar support comma-separated value lists (`.csv`) as well, but this will not be compatible with iCal.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to create. But I don't want to program it. Is there a program or web app that would take my event details and give me a .ics and/or a .csv link?

Comment: Where are your event details coming from? Are you exporting from any sort of calendar program like Outlook or something? What is your website running - are you using any sort of CMS like WordPress or SilverStripe? Depending on your setup, any of a number of solutions could work. Post more details and I'll give you a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video that explains how to put an "Add this event to your Outlook calendar" link on your website:

> http://video.answers.com/create-an-add-this-event-file-for-your-website-57402874

I haven't tried it yet, but it doesn't seem complicated.